# difference between bind-web-address and volttron-central-address

Tags: volttron

I entered information for the volttron central instance as follows:

```
cat ~/.volttron-master/config

[volttron]
bind-web-address = http://192.168.1.31:8080
vip-address = tcp://192.168.1.31:22916
instance-name = "central tcp://192.168.1.31"
volttron-central-address = http://192.168.1.31:8080
```

What is the difference between bind-web-address and volttron-central-address? 
In my opinion, the former is required for the web service, and the latter is for entering the address of the instance to control this instance.
Can the port number be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is context.  Bind web address is opening a port on the machine that is going to be the web server.  The volttron central address is used as the location to look for the web server.  I hope that makes sense.

They should be the same when your Vc and VCP are on the same instance.